# find the indices of rows in a pandas data frame for which the column values lie in a list

Tags: python, pandas

```
list1 = [25,18,65]
customer=pd.DataFrame({
    'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'name':['Olivia','Aditya','Cory','Isabell','Dominic','Tyler','Samuel','Daniel','Jeremy'],
    'age':[20,25,15,10,30,65,35,18,23],
    'Product_ID':[101,0,106,0,103,104,106,0,107]
})
```

I need to extract the indices of the rows with ages in list1.
I tried

```
customer[customer['age'] in list1]].index
```

but this gives me an error

````
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().```
````

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `in`, you should use `isin`:

```
customer[customer['age'].isin(list1)]].index
```

You can't use `in` in pandas, you only can use [`pd.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).